# convert every 100th element of an array into comma separated string

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array that varies in size, can be anywhere from 1 to 200000.

I want to loop through this array, then save the values into a comma separated string, and if the size is greater than 100, save the first 100 into the string, \perform my operation\ come back for the next 100 continuing from the next value in the array

```
$users = $this->_db->get('search_results', array('search_token', '=' , $search_token) );
$results = $users-> results();
$unique = $users->count();

foreach($results as $result){
  print_r($result->id); //print each id.
}
```

it's the id values from the results that i'm trying to get into the string, all I am doing right now is printing.

i think it should be something like

```
$string = "0,1,2,3,5,5.....99";
dosomething($string);
```

then the loop updates string with "100,101,102,103,104......145"

but i can't figure it out, I'll modify the suggestions I have and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: A simple `foreach($results as $counter => $result){ if (($counter % 100) !== 0) { echo ','; } echo $result->id; }` will allow you to test for every 100th element

Answer (score 0):

Basically keep track of a `$counter` and loop through the array concatenating the array items into a string along the way. When you reach your 100th element do your operation (in the example I will just add a comma for each 10th element, but the idea is the same).

```
$array = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','n','m','o','p','q','r','s','t');

$eleNum = 10; // This is 10 for the sake of example, it can be changed to 100
$counter = 0; // Our counter

$string = ""; // The comma separated string

foreach( $array as $item ) { // For every item in array
    $string .= $item;
    $counter++;
    if( $counter % $eleNum == 0 ) { // If it's out 10th (100th), add comma
        $string .= ",";
        $counter = 0;
    }
}

echo $string;
```

Would give the output:

```
abcdefghij,klnmopqrst,
```